# Write multiple Sum() SQL query using Lambda in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, lambda

Below is my SQL query that I'm looking to convert to Lambda

```
SELECT
    SUM("Rating" * "Rating") / SUM("Rating")
FROM 
    public."CustomerRating" 
WHERE 
    "DriverId" = '232'
```

This is my C# code:

```
public double GetDriverAvgRating(string id)
{
    var driver = _context.CustomerRating
                         .AsQueryable()
                         .Where(d => d.DriverId == id);

    var avgDriverRating = // i need to perform that query here

    return avgDriverRating;
}
```

Comment: What difficulty are you having, it seems a fairly simple exercise. Do you have any code so far? I must say, the writer of this code seems to have forgotten how to square a number

Comment: Have you setup a db context yet? Also, do you really need a switch case? `SELECT SUM(["Rating"]*["Rating"]) / SUM(["Rating"]) FROM public."CustomerRating"` seems like what you'd want.

Comment: Thank you john. I have updated my C# code above

Comment: Your sql has no WHERE. Your c# has a Where. Which shall it be?

Comment: Is rating always an integer between 1 and 5?

Comment: Yes the rating is between 1 to 5 and i have updated my WHERE part in the sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe EF will be able to correctly translate it as a grouping, something like

```
var driver = _context.CustomerRating
  .Where(cr => cr.DriverId == id)
  .GroupBy(cr => cr.DriverId, cr => cr.Rating)
  .Select(g => g.Select(r => r * r).Sum() /  g.Sum())
  .First();
```

It might have some extra fluff in the query (eg a group by that produces only one group) but I don't expect it'll make any significant difference to the overall performance/planning of the query